# Include .sh file in .pl file and access variable of .pl file in .sh

Tags: perl, shell

```
In .pl script.
..
//variables
my $var;
system("sh main.sh");
..

In .sh script.
// can I used here, some variables of declare in .pl file.
```

How to used the .pl file variables in .sh file. and obvious.. have used the .sh file
Thanx!

Comment: Can anyone tell me Is it possible or Not?

Comment: why dont you just pass the variable to the .sh script?

Comment: I have include the .sh file into .pl so, some variable need in that file .sh which calculate in .pl var.

Comment: that doesnt make sense, why dont you post your code so we can see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Pranay, I think what Chris means is calling your shell script like this: `system 'sh main.sh', $var;` and then access `$var` in the shell script as its argument.

Comment: No, you haven't included the `.sh` file into the `.pl` file. You've *called* it.

Comment: Use arguments or environment variables.

Comment: @Flimm this question is done but, can you give me the ans of another question that I have asked before 1 hour. Thanx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791204/delete-rows-with-mysqldump-backup-table this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child (`sh`) will receive the contents of `%ENV` as its environment.

```
$ perl -e'local $ENV{VAR} = "VAL"; system("sh", "-c", q{printf "%s\n" "$VAR"})'
VAL
```

You could also pass the values as arguments.

```
$ perl -e'my $var = "VAL"; system("sh", "-c", q{printf "%s\n" "$1"}, "-", $var)'
VAL
```

Comment: What exactly this line do? pls tell me. I did not get this line.

Comment: Hey @ikegami please can we chat on email ID.?

Comment: `sh -c cmd` is the same thing as `sh script` where `script` contains `cmd`. // `local $ENV{VAR} = "VAL";` sets var `$ENV{VAR}`, and I already explained why. // `my $var = "VAL";` sets var `$var`.

Comment: [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23080/discussion-between-pranay-and-ikegami)

Comment: Can you send me your mail ID.SO, I will tell you my problem. I have accept the answer because. I get the logic. But, It oes down for problem so, can you paste here your mail ID.

Comment: When I want to work on these kinds of problems, I come here. You have no need for my address. You can write in [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23080/discussion-between-pranay-and-ikegami). If you include `@ikegami` in a message, it will notify me of the message.

Comment: But, I dont have 20+ reputation

Comment: So, I cant refer for chat